# DBGrid How to hide Titles row and Indicator column?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, tdbgrid

Is there a way to hide the Titles row and the Indicator column on a DBGrid? I couldn't find any property of this kind. Can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn off (set to False) the `Options.dgTitles` and `Options.dgIndicator` in the Object Inspector, or remove them in code:

```
DBGrid1.Options := DBGrid1.Options - [dgTitles, dgIndicator];
```

Comment: Ken. I'm really an idiot! I knew there was a simple way to do it, but I was looking for a specific property in the Object Inspector. My sinceer appology!